# How pass image to Asp.net web api Controller and display it?

Tags: json, byte

I passed the image value in json format.then i Stored image value in byte array in Database. then how can i retrieve value from Database and display as image?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and you can see the implementation I came up with here: 
Visit: http://jamessdixon.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/handling-images-in-webapi/

I hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

The implementation depends on how you are going to display the image.

You can do this. Use a asp:Image control and from code behind set the source like below.

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
```

To explain, first get the stored bytes from database. Then convert that in to base64String